# Failed to Deploy WAR to JBoss EAP 7

Tags: java, jboss

I am trying to deploy a WAR file to a local instance of the RedHat JBoss EAP 7 server. However whenever I attempt to deploy it the below error comes up.

```
12:55:05,442 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) 
MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."ABC-ws-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ABC-ws-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "ABC-ws-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.WSIntegrationProcessorJAXWS_POJO.getUrlPattern(WSIntegrationProcessorJAXWS_POJO.java:212)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.WSIntegrationProcessorJAXWS_POJO.processAnnotation(WSIntegrationProcessorJAXWS_POJO.java:102)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.AbstractIntegrationProcessorJAXWS.deploy(AbstractIntegrationProcessorJAXWS.java:74)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    ... 5 more
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I take it the WAR has a servlet?  It looks like based on the "WSIntegrationProcessorJAXWS_POJO" code that it's trying to figure out the URL of your servlet and it cannot find any match.  Do you have an "@WebServlet" annotation and if so can you paste it?

Comment: Were you able to get it figured out?